# searchParams not changing the URL via Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using this script to dynamically change the URL from `example.com/?gclid=456` to `example.com/?gclid=456&client_id=123`

I tried the below script, but it doesn't work. Please note, the Cookie value is populating. Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong?

```
function () {
  var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*=example]');
  links.forEach(function(link) {            
    var original = new URL(link.getAttribute('href'));
    var search_params = original.searchParams;  
    search_params.set('client_id', {{Read gaClientId}});
    link.href=original;            
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply `.append` the new arguments.

```
let x = new URL('https://example.com/?gclid=456')
x.searchParams.append('test',1234)
```

Comment: ok, so if users come on this link, https://example.com and they click the button, this is how append will work -  https://example.com?client_id=123

Either they come via gclid parameters or organically.

Comment: Search params don't work. This works, but I don't want to use this code.  


<script>
(function () {


var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*=example]');
var clientId = '?client_id={{Read gaClientId}}'

links.forEach(function(link) {
              
var original = link.getAttribute('href');
link.setAttribute('href', original+clientId)
              
                            
 })


}) ();
  
</script>

Comment: The point is that you do not need `var search_params = original.searchParams;` all you have to do is `.append`.